# How to have mySQL return data that is grouped in multiple "tiers"

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, performance, multidimensional-array

Is there any way to query a mysql db and have it return a result that is grouped like this:

```
- 12/16/2010
  -daily
    - Ad Source 1, uniques, hits, rev
    - Ad Source 2, uniques, hits, rev
    - Ad Source 3, uniques, hits, rev
    - Ad Source 4, uniques, hits, rev
  -total
    - total uniques, total hits, total rev

- 12/15/2010
  -daily
    - Ad Source 1, uniques, hits, rev
    - Ad Source 2, uniques, hits, rev
    - Ad Source 3, uniques, hits, rev
    - Ad Source 4, uniques, hits, rev
  -total
    - total uniques, total hits, total rev
```

Right now if I want to get revenue on a daily basis for a site I get a result like this from mySQL:

- 12/16/2010, ad source 1, uniques, hits, rev
- 12/16/2010, ad source 2, uniques, hits, rev
- 12/16/2010, ad source 3, uniques, hits, rev
- 12/16/2010, ad source 4, uniques, hits, rev
- 12/15/2010, ad source 1, uniques, hits, rev
- 12/15/2010, ad source 2, uniques, hits, rev
- 12/15/2010, ad source 3, uniques, hits, rev
- 12/15/2010, ad source 4, uniques, hits, rev

Then I need to run a second query to get the total amounts for 12/16/2010 and 12/15/2010, and on top of that I need to have PHP group it by the day

The table I am querying is setup like this:
ad_source_num, date, uniques, hits, rev

I feel like there must be a more efficient way of getting data returned. can anybody help :-(

Answer (score 0):

"more efficient way" -- now you already follow the efficient way. 2 queries often is not worse than 1. And now you have the case, when it is completely true.

Comment: Right, but when it comes to grouping all the data for display to the user I need to use PHP move the data into a multi-dimensional array. Isn't there a way of having mySQL return it to me organized like I have it above in the first example?

Comment: @Brendan: sure no. The database is for storing and processing the information. How you will display it - database should not care of. And actually I can't get why do you need **multi-dimensional** array, since the output you need can be retrieved from the flat array, just gotten from mysql.

Comment: A multi-dimensional array is preferential in the situation I am in. If I use a flat array, I need to worry about organizing which data from which ad source goes with which day. If there was a way to do something like GROUP BY (date) and have the results from each date be grouped by ad_source.

Comment: @Brendan: there is no way. Mysql knows nothing about such data structures (multidimensional arrays) in php.

Answer (score 0):

First, a query to get the grouped daily numbers:

```
SELECT id, ad_source_num, date, SUM(uniques) AS uniques, SUM(hits) AS hits, SUM(rev) AS rev FROM advertdata
GROUP BY date, ad_source_num ORDER BY date DESC, ad_source_num ASC
```

Then a second query (almost identical) to get the totals:

```
SELECT id, ad_source_num, date, SUM(uniques) AS uniques, SUM(hits) AS hits, SUM(rev) AS rev FROM advertdata
GROUP BY date ORDER BY date DESC, ad_source_num ASC
```

Comment: This is what I am currently doing, however the data returned is not organized, the days are not grouped together (other than by ordering)

Comment: Could you post the queries you're currently using? If they *are* the same as mine you are already getting the days back grouped and your question turns into "In PHP, how can I get my results from MySQL into a multidimensional array formatted in this exact way?"

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is the WITH ROLLUP declaration with your GROUP BY.

```
SELECT date, ad_source, SUM(uniques) AS u, SUM(hits) AS h, SUM(rev) AS r FROM tablename GROUP BY date, ad_source WITH ROLLUP
```

That will give you an extra "total" line whenever the date field changes.

Answer (score 0):

Wait.  Stop. Teach the man to fish, not give away the fish.

How about a design philosophy? How about a methodology?   There are always problems like this to be solved.

Try writing a model that describes that data that you want. It could be useful in many situations. Sometimes you data may come from two different sources, then SQL is out zee window.

```
 public function get_crap($start_date, $end_date)
    {
    $return = array();
    foreach (valid_date_range($start_date, $end_date) as $date)
         {
         $return[$date] = daily_crap_from($date, $this->db);
         }
     return $return;
    } 

 static function daily_crap_from($mm_dd_yyyy, $db) 
   {
   $return = array();
   $db->query("select * from daily_crap_lines where day like '".$mm_dd_yyyy."'")
   while ($c = $db->next_record())
      {
      $return[] = $c;
      }
    return $return;
   }
```